# Two men and a door, but no liar

Tags: riddle, word

You come across a door, guarded by two mysterious men. As you start to figure out how to tell which one is lying and which one is telling the truth, they say in unison:

> ***WELCOME, TRAVELER, TO REIBELLO'S RIDDLE REPOSITORY.  SHOULD YOU SEEK ENTRY, YOU'LL HAVE TO SOLVE A SIMPLE PUZZLE.***

You quickly agree to hear the puzzle.  You also notice that their voices are different.  One is deep and **strong**, while the other is softer, and strangely *emphatic* about his words.

> **Our first AND second facilitate, that which you need to operate.**
>
> *Each alone, is not correct, but read aloud make our subject.*
>
> **Our third is imprecise at best, but gladly taken on a test.**
>
> *Our fourth is five-* **It's two.  His clues are the worst.  It's also half of what is first.**
>
> **Our fifth is fifth.  All the clue you'll need, I reckon.** *But just in case, it's also our second.*
>
> *Our sixth and last, core of our planet round, but don't go quite as far in underground.*
>
> ***Our riddle complete, answer if you dare.  Six letters, and no more, WE SWEAR.***

What word are the mysterious men looking for?

Answer (score 3):

The mysterious men are looking for the word:

> WEAVER.

```
Our first AND second facilitate, that which you need to operate.
```

> WE (not sure)

```
Each alone, is not correct, but read aloud make our subject.
```

> ???

```
Our third is imprecise at best, but gladly taken on a test.
```

> A. Imprecise ???. Anyone would be glad to receive an A as a test score.

```
Our fourth is five- It's two. His clues are the worst. It's also half of what is first.
```

> V. V is 5 in roman numerals. V is also half of W.

```
Our fifth is fifth. All the clue you'll need, I reckon. But just in case, it's also our second.
```

> E. E is the 5th letter of the alphabet. This is the same as the 2nd letter.

```
Our sixth and last, core of our planet round, but don't go quite as far in underground.
```

> R. Middle letter of Ea**r**th. Also appears in unde**r**g**r**ound

```
Our riddle complete, answer if you dare. Six letters, and no more, WE SWEAR.
```

> WE SWEAR = WE AVER

Comment: You've got the answer right - see if you can get the first two letters.  There's a bit of a jump.

Comment: Perhaps "A" for "imprecise at best" refers to the fact that the best is "A+", so just "A" isn't quite it. As for the first two, it might refer to the two speakers weaving words together.

Comment: rot13("jr" vf n fhowrpg (nf bccbfrq gb na bowrpg))

Comment: Pay less attention to "we" right now (thought we as a subject is going to be important) and try and figure out what two completely different letters the first hint wants.